# Why doesn’t my jQuery code work on mobile platforms?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a gallery of images that grow when clicked. I set the height value with the following jQuery code so that the images always appear at a ratio of 4/3.

```
var gallery_item_width = $(".gallery-item").width();
var gallery_item_height = (gallery_item_width / 4) * 3;
$(".gallery-item").css("height", gallery_item_height);
```

Although my code works fine on desktop, when I switch to mobile view, my jQuery code does not work and the height of the images is equal to one line height.

Why is my code not working properly on mobile? Thank you for your help

Html

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-01.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-01.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-02.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-02.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-03.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-06.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-05.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-05.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-06.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-01.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-01.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-02.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-02.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-06.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item trigger">
        <div class="gallery-img bg-img" style="background-image:url('img/bg-03.jpg');">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="gallery-filter"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
        <div class="lightbox"><img src="img/bg-05.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.gallery-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: -25px 0 0px -25px;
}

.gallery-item {
    flex: 1 1 18%;
    margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.gallery-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.gallery-filter {
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 900;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    background-color: var(--light-filter);
    color: var(--light-grey-text);
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery-filter:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: var(--dark-filter);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.lightbox img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .gallery-wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .gallery-item {
        margin: 0px 0px 25px 0px;
    }

    .gallery-item:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .gallery-filter:hover {
        opacity: 0;
    }

}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var gallery_item_width = $(".gallery-item").width();

    var gallery_item_height = (gallery_item_width / 4) * 3;

    $(".gallery-item").css("height", gallery_item_height);

});

if ($(window).width() > 768) {

    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".lightbox").toggle();
    });

}
```

Comment: I guess it the event 'ready' of jquery does't trigger on mobile browser.

Comment: I've created a fiddle but it doesn't toggle even in desktop mode https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/a45e3gws/1/ ? i might not be understanding correctly the problem here

Comment: @Rick the ready event should run ok in mobile

Comment: ok,i was wrong.@joshmoto

Comment: You should perform debugging. What is the screen width in mobile? What is the value of `gallery_item_width` in mobile view? Does your code cater screen orientation changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with jquery.It is caused by the following css.

```css
    .gallery-item {
        flex: 1 1 18%; /* error */
        margin: 25px 0 0 25px;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Remove the flex style,then it work ok.